# Moving the cursor to a newly added row in a table in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my function which fetches `data` from an `API` based on the `barcode`. No entered by the user and then populates rest of the table. After this it checks for some required fields and then adds a new row to the table.

```js
  const handleSaveCell = async (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
    const updatedTableData = [...tableData];
    updatedTableData[rowIndex][columnId] = value;

    // Call fetchData function when user leaves Barcode cell
    if (columnId === "Barcode" && value.trim() !== "") {
      try {
        const response = await fetchData(value.trim());
        const itemData = response.length > 0 ? response[0] : {}; // Check if response has any elements

        // Update the row data with the fetched data
        updatedTableData[rowIndex] = {
          ...updatedTableData[rowIndex],
          ItemName: itemData?.ItemName || "",
          HSN: itemData?.HSN || "",
          Size: itemData?.Size || "",
          SPrice: itemData?.SPrice || "",
          Qty: 1, // set Qty to 1 by default
          GSTInclusive: itemData?.GSTInclusive || "",
          CGST: itemData?.CGST || "",
          SGST: itemData?.SGST || "",
          IGST: itemData?.IGST || "",
          TaxAmt: itemData?.SPrice || "",
          Amount: itemData?.SPrice || "", // set Amount to SPrice initially
        };

        const barcodeVal = updatedTableData[rowIndex]["Barcode"];
        const itemNameVal = itemData?.ItemName || "";
        const qtyVal = String(updatedTableData[rowIndex]["Qty"]).trim();
        const amountVal = String(updatedTableData[rowIndex]["Amount"]).trim();

        // Check if all required fields have data and add a new row
        if (
          barcodeVal.trim() !== "" &&
          itemNameVal.trim() !== "" &&
          qtyVal.trim() !== "" &&
          amountVal.trim() !== ""
        ) {
          updatedTableData.push(
            columns.reduce((obj, column) => {
              obj[column.accessorKey] = "";
              return obj;
            }, {})
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle error
      }
    } else if (columnId === "Qty") {
      // Update Amount when Qty changes
      const qty = parseFloat(value) || 0;
      const sprice = parseFloat(updatedTableData[rowIndex]["SPrice"]) || 0;
      updatedTableData[rowIndex]["TaxAmt"] = qty * sprice;
    }

    setTableData(updatedTableData);

    const nonEmptyTableData = updatedTableData.filter((rowData) => {
      return Object.values(rowData).some((value) => value !== "");
    });

    sendTableData(nonEmptyTableData);
  };
```

I tried focus using `useRef` hooks, I tried `scrollintoview` none of them works. Neither does it works nor do I get any errors. Any possible solutions??

Comment: Is it always visible? `scrollIntoView` only shows the data. `focus` is only possible on focusable input-elements and makes them focused, not changing the cursor. Are you looking for the `select` method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

Comment: the cells in my table has input element and I just want the focus or cursor to move to the newly added row. Its a sales form I dont want user to manually select barcode field and then enter the barcode every time thats why I want that the cursor moves to the input element in the barcode cell as soon as the barcode is entered and the data is fetched and populated in the rest of the cells. If you want I can add my return block of code as well which is rendering the table.